# auto renaming batch file

Tags: batch-file, rename

I need to create a batch file that will strip the first four characters from a file name and dump the rest.  so basically I may have file "1234_whatever.txt" and I need it to rename the file to "1234.txt"  The format of the file name will always be the same however the filenames will always change.  On top of that I need this to be all automatic with no user intervention.  any help would be appreciated

Comment: If it is one file in each case then it can be done more simply.  Or is it a folder full?  Or subfolders?

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=."
FOR %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\*_*.*") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%b IN ("%%a") DO IF NOT "%%c"=="" (
 ECHO(REN "%%a" %%~nb%%~xa
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You'd need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to your directoryname.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Note that the SHORT filename for longfilenames will typically contain an underscore, and will be hit by the `dir` command. Hence the requirement for the `if not "%%c==""`

You may wish to change `*_*.*` to `*_*.txt` if you only wish to process `.txt` files.