# Rename using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I am trying to create a batch file (.bat) that will rename any files in a folder to remove all but the first 6 numbers. The files will be PDF, but renaming all files in a folder is fine. An example of a filename would be 123456-AmortizedLoanStatement-123456-094644982.pdf. I'd like for it to be 123456.pdf

I found a similar post on this but I couldn't get that code to work: [auto renaming batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691158/auto-renaming-batch-file)

Thank you guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [auto renaming batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691158/auto-renaming-batch-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is all you need:

```dos
Ren "C:\path to\a folder\??????-*.pdf" "??????.pdf"
```

*(It assumes that you do not have multiple files beginning with the same six characters)*

Answer (score 1):

[Magoo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21692558/6811411) batch is perfectly suited for your task,
you just have to change the delimiter from `_` to `-` in two places and select the extension.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=."
FOR %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\*-*.pdf") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=-" %%b IN ("%%a") DO IF NOT "%%c"=="" (
 ECHO(REN "%%a" %%~nb%%~xa
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

That wasn't to hard to find.